# How to change the size of icon inside input using css?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple input which contains an icon on the right side and text on the left side

Here is what I would like to have in mobile version:

[image]

here is what I have so far in desktop version

[image]

HTML

```
  <div class="form_group">
   <input id="input-icon" type="text" class="form_input " placeholder="W jakim celu z nami kontaktujesz?">
</div>
```

csss

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 375px)
.form_input {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 342px;
}
#input-icon {
    background: url(../images/arrow-mobile.png) no-repeat scroll 7px 7px;
    background-position: right;
    /* opacity: 0.4; */
}
```

**

> UPDATE

**
To simplify things here is my jsfiddle with the icon I am using :

http://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/z0x6uta2/2/

what do I need to do get what I want? I tried opacity but didn't work as expected?

Comment: Are you using any font icon packs like fontawesome or something by chance? Could show a different technique that would be more resolution friendly all together.

Comment: Chris no am not using font awesome, am using custom icon ;)

Comment: The code you supplied suggest you are using some library for the design, Please let us know which one. or supply all the relevant code to achieve the same screenshot.

Comment: @domestic no its just clean html nothing is used here

Comment: Well, applying the opacity to the input directly will effect the whole input, the media query needs to bracket those classes below it to apply them (unless that's just a typo in the example) but as it's just a png, could always add your opacity to the png file itself and swap out images or use another element to place it there instead of the input and apply the opacity to it instead.

Comment: Your right , I noticed that so I decided to do differently , looks simple but damn :( here is js if you still wondering if am using library , http://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/z0x6uta2/2/

Answer (score 3):

```css
.form_input {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 342px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#input-icon {
    background: url(https://thumb.ibb.co/iAQtup/arrow_mobile.png) no-repeat scroll 7px 7px;
    background-size: 7px;
    background-position: right;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="form_group">
   <input id="input-icon" type="text" class="form_input " placeholder="W jakim celu z nami kontaktujesz?">
</div>
```

Result Preview:

[image]

Comment: your code seems just fine.i would guess the media query is wrong. (click Run code to see the result)

Comment: @Domentic your code does not give us expected result , here is jsfidle with icon am using http://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/z0x6uta2/2/

Comment: Your solution is close to what I want but what about placeholder? I want it also to be hidden

Comment: am not sure what you refer to, the placeholder is faded out also.
see image.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this.

```css
.form_input {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 342px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
#input-icon {
    background: url('https://thumb.ibb.co/iAQtup/arrow_mobile.png') no-repeat scroll 7px 7px;
    background-position: 100%;
    background-size: 4%;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="form_group">
   <input id="input-icon" type="text" class="form_input " placeholder="W jakim celu z nami kontaktujesz?">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution based on Dementic's answer ,

```
.form_input {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 342px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
#input-icon {
    background: url('https://thumb.ibb.co/iAQtup/arrow_mobile.png') no-repeat scroll 5px 5px;
    background-position: right;
   background-size: 12px;
   height: 4px;
   opacity: 0.4;
 }

.form_input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
        color: transparent;
        }
```

jsfiddle for anyone interest to see the expected result

http://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/z0x6uta2/16/

Thanks all for help #StopActa2Though

Answer (score 0):

you are able to change icon size inside the input field using  `background-size:20px;`
example is given below according to your code

```
#input-icon {
              background-size: 20px;
            }
```